# Python - Memory Error whilst loading values to get a fourier transform

Tags: python

I'm loading in a 500000 kb (0.5Gb) text file of a single column which consists of a series of voltages read in via a daq card.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import scipy.fftpack as spf

File = np.loadtxt('testinghpython.txt')

volt = File[:]

FFTX = abs(sp.fft(volt))
freqx = spf.fftfreq(len(volt),dt)

plt.figure(2)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Fast fourier Transform of Voltage')
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.plot(freqx,10*np.log10(FFTX))
plt.clf

plt.show()
```

However I'm getting the error

```
    X.append(items)
MemoryError
```

I assume this is because it's a large dataset.

Is there anyway to go ahead and calculate the fourier transform without reading them all into memory? Or does this require me reading in the entire text file into memory? This pc has about 8gb of RAM so I'm not entirely sure as to how to get it to use the rest of the available memory. I think I'm on 32 bit spyder, will I have to switch to 64 bit?

Comment: What is `volt.bytes`?

Comment: Unfortunately the program doesn't even finish Values = np.loadtxt before having the Memory error